# No token response returned when using Trusted Origin in Direct Line OAuth

Tags: .net, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I seem to be hitting an issue when using trusted origins with the OAuthPrompt (Generic Oauth2 w/ ADB2C) and a waterfall dialog. The first step is ensuring the user is authenticated, the next collects the token response from the step context result and continues. This all works fine w/ the magic code.

```
public async Task<DialogTurnResult> EnsureUserAuthenticated(WaterfallStepContext sc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     return await sc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);
}

public async Task<DialogTurnResult> AskForDateTime(WaterfallStepContext sc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

{
     var tokenResponse = sc.Result as TokenResponse;
     ...
}
```

I've tried this locally and in Azure and after the auth browser window closes, nothing happens. You have to re-trigger the waterfall dialog to get the token response returned in the 2nd step.

This bot is being surfaced using CDN WebChat.

Any ideas what may be going wrong?

Comment: Just to confirm for repro: does this go straight from EnsureUserAuthenticated to AskForDateTime?

Comment: Yes, it should. It does when Trusted Origin is disabled.  If I click the same adaptive card button again to re-trigger the same flow, AskForDateTime does get called right after EnsureUserAuthenticated - I'm guessing it has the token cached at this point.

`var steps = new WaterfallStep[]
{
 EnsureUserAuthenticated,
 AskForDate,
 AskToProvideShowTitle,
 AskForShowTitle,
 ConfirmWithUser,
 FinishDialog,
};`

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me: https://blog.botframework.com/2018/09/25/enhanced-direct-line-authentication-features/

My understanding is that by default, WebChat is secured so that OAuthCard sign-in links do not result in a ‘verification code’ response. 
The Emulator uses the WebChat control to display the conversation with the bot.

We could simulate the magic token experience inside emulator . For that ensure that ‘Use a sign-in verification code for OAuthCards’ is checked inside the settings of the emulator.If it works inside emulator ,the code is perfectly fine.

Comment: This all works without trusted origins enabled (magic code). To my understanding, there isn't any difference in the way the bot handles the acceptance of the token response outside of the json payload sent to the token request REST API.